# Clean up if else statement

Tags: python

**Background**

I have a simple logic where i get `total_kits`. I usually make some function call to get the value for this variable. Then if `total_kits` is less than some `MIN_KITS_THRESHOLD` then i want to print some message and do nothing. If `is_delivery_created_earlier_today()` function returns true i also want to print some message and do nothing. If both those condtions are not violated then i want to call my function `launch_pipeline()`.

I am basically using a if elif else but i am wondering if i can organize my if else statements to be more clean.

**Code**

```
total_kits = #Some number
if total_kits < MIN_KITS_THRESHOLD:
    # print some message but don't launch pipeline
elif is_delivery_created_earlier_today():
    # print some message but don't launch pipeline
else:
    launch_pipeline()
```

Comment: are the two messages mutually exclusive?

Comment: Please provide more complete code - e.g. complete script. ["_there are significant pieces of the core functionality missing, and we need you to fill in the details. Excerpts of large projects are fine, but if you have omitted too much, then reviewers are left imagining how your program works._"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3652/120114)

Comment: Also, the current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as  [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/120114) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: @TedBrownlow no they are not mutually exclusive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `launch_pipeline()` shown as a function, so I'll assume that you are comfortable with writing functions.

Create a *boolean* function, something like `is_pipeline_allowed()`, and put your reasons inside that.

```
total_kits = get_number_of_kits()

if is_pipeline_allowed(total_kits):
    launch_pipeline()
```

Elsewhere:

```
def is_pipeline_allowed(nkits):
    if nkits < MIN_KITS_THRESHOLD:
        print("not enough kits for pipeline to launch")
        return False
   
    if is_delivery_created_earlier_today():
        print("pipeline has already launched for today")
        return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

If the code blocks below the `if` and `elif` are identical, you can merge those conditions into:

```
total_kits = #Some number
if total_kits < MIN_KITS_THRESHOLD or is_delivery_created_earlier_today():
    # print some message but don't launch pipeline
else:
    launch_pipeline()
```

Otherwise I do not see a reason to change anything in this snippet.